# Why is the .__proto__ of the base object in Javascript null instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
var a = {};
console.log(a.__proto__); // shows the base object
console.log(a.__proto__.__proto__); // shows the prototype of the base object as "null".
```

Why isn't it undefined (as it is never declared as a property in the base object)?

Comment: `null` typically shows deliberate absence. This doesn't seem accidental to me. Ultimately, though - why does it really matter which "it's not here" value was used to say "it's not here"?

Answer (score 3):

`null` indicates an intentional absence of a value, typically of an object value. From [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-null-value):

> **null value**
>
> primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value

In contrast, for `undefined` [it says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-undefined-value):

> **undefined value**
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value

`Object.prototype`'s prototype is *intentionlly* set to indicate that there's no prototype, and separately prototype objects are, well, objects, so `null` for "no object" makes the most sense.

---

That said, beware of "why" questions with JavaScript, because although most of them have perfectly reasonable explanations, some of the most odd things just come down to "Because that's what Brendan Eich thought he should do at the time" and/or "Because there was a bug in the original implementation that got copied by other implementations and couldn't be changed without breaking existing code, so it had to be put in the spec." (For instance, that's why `typeof null` is `"object"` rather than `"null"`.) I'm not saying don't ask "why" questions, because again, often there's a good reason that can lead to a better understanding of the language. Just beware that sometimes, well, there just isn't.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks a lot! So I guess this is the Javascript's creator's way of saying that "I'm at the root now, look no further" intentionally?

Comment: @WanderingDoge - Yup! Also note that it's not just `Object.prototype`, you can do this with your own objects if you have some reason they shouldn't inherit from `Object.prototype`: `const obj = Object.create(null);` creates an object with no prototype. `const obj2 = Object.create(obj);` creates an object with `obj` as its prototype but which doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`. Before we had `Map`, that was useful for avoiding having things like `hasOwnProperty` and `toString` on objects you were using as key/value maps. But now we have `Map`. :-)